# Proof of this theorem " The equation $x^2=2$ has a unique positive real solution "

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove this by, letting $S=\{x\in Q; x>0, x^2<2\}\subset R$
, then say there exist least upper-bound y, s.t $y^2=2$,
anyone knows how can I prove this ? or where I can find more details about it?

Comment: $S$ is a bounded subset of real numbers, so $S$ has a l.u.b., call it $y.$ If $y^2>2, $ you should be able to get some sort of contradiction.

Comment: You need to show that there is a positive real solution (and use the properties of the reals to do this, since on the rationals you cannot show it), and that this is a unique positive real solution (in contrast say to $x^2=4x-2$ having more than one positive real solution)